# Are components intended for data creation in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new to Ember and trying to get my head around all this new Ember concepts.

Currently I am struggling in finding the best way for data creation.

What I want to do is, create a file upload that creates a model instance at the same time by accessing a micro service with two AJAX calls.

Because this upload form should be used in several places, a components seems the right choice.

So how would one build a component that does this?

1. Should I create a component and perform the AJAX calls there while bypassing Ember Data?
2. Should I handle over some model data to the component and do the AJAX calls via the model's data adapter?
3. Am I completely wrong here and there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there are a few approaches to do this. First yes, a component is definitely something you need.

I don't think you should bypass ember-data. There are really few reasons to do this. Probably what you want to do is:

1. To create a record with `store.createRecord()`,
2. modify that record,
3. `.save()` it,
4. and handle all `ajax` stuff in the adapter.

You basically have two ways to do this:

- You could call an action from the component after you have all data, and do all the stuff above in that action. I think thats the most DDAU approach. With this approach your connection to the outside world is explicit when calling the component `{{file-upload onUpload=(action 'upload')}}`.
- You can inject the store into the component. Honestly thats what I would do. The store is just a service, so thats easy. And then you can just create your record. However your connection to the store is less explicit.

Comment: OK. Injecting the store into the component seems to be the pragmatic way. I think calling an action would be problematic if I need to give feedback like progess during upload back to the component?

Comment: @JPS well its possible. actions have return values, and you could give status down with data.